# checking if an string array raw is last one

Tags: php, arrays

do anyone know how to Check if my string raw is last one i tried using end(...) but i'm stuck how to check if the string array raw is last one on the array for example

```
$array = array('raw1' => 'value1', 'raw2' => 'value2', 'raw3' => 'value3');
for($array as $key => $value) {
   if(strcmp(end($array), $key) == False) { // some code which will be excuted when the check returns true  } 
}
```

iamn't sure if my example is correct but please could anyone help me checking if the array raw is last one ?? please

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`end()`](https://www.php.net/end)

```
$array = array('raw1' => 'value1', 'raw2' => 'value2', 'raw3' => 'value3');
$lastElement = end($array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($v == $lastElement) {
        // some code which will be executed its last element of an array  
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Comment: can't upvote i haven't enough reputation but i have marked it as answer. thanks for both of your & @talgat

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$array = array('raw1' => 'value1', 'raw2' => 'value2', 'raw3' => 'value3');
$arrayCount = count($array);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    if ($arrayCount == $i) {
        // some code which will be excuted
    }
}
```